# How can I plot my curve, so it can be seen that it is a spiral?

Tags: matlab, maple

I want to plot the parametric curve $ [\exp(-1/(1-t) )\cos(1/(1-t)) , \, \exp(-1/(1-t)) \sin(1/(1-t)) ]$ for $ t \in [0,1] $ in Maple or Matlab. It should look like a spiral which winds infinitley often around $(0,0)$, but when I plot it, all I can get is an arc which goes to $ (0,0) $ and does not look like a spiral. Is there a way to plot this curve, to see the behaviour of a spiral?

Comment: The first  thing I would do is let $u=  \frac{1}{1-t}$  so that the equations became $x= e^{-u}cos(u)$, $y= e^{-u}sin(u)$ with u going from 1 to infinity.  Of course, instead of infinity, take the upper limit to be some sufficiently large number.

Comment: I have tried it, but it still does not look like a spiral ...

Comment: [This Desmos plot](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/u7kvedu9n7) should help you see it.  As you zoom you should continue seeing more of the spiral.

Comment: Thank you ! But is it also possible to plot it somehow in Maple or Matlab, to see the spiral ?

Comment: Seems like MATLAB is a programming language. Not sure if this question should be migrated to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) though.

Comment: I tried messing with this parametric plot in Maple. I'm guessing that there is simply not an easy way to visualize the infinite spiraling behavior you describe. It requires fine detail and a pretty advanced UI that Maple simply does not have (but Desmos does). I wish I could help more, but I'm at my wit's end.

Answer (score 1):

In Maple,

```
ee := [exp(-1/(1-t))*cos(1/(1-t)),
       exp(-1/(1-t))*sin(1/(1-t))]:

plot([ee[], t=0..1]);
```

[image]

You could also make an interactive app, to illustrate zooming in on that. For example,

```
ee := [exp(-1/(1-t))*cos(1/(1-t)),exp(-1/(1-t))*sin(1/(1-t))]:
ff := eval(ee,t=a):
Explore(plots:-display(
    plots:-textplot([ff[], sprintf("t = %.3g",a)],
                    align={piecewise(sin(1/(1-a))<0,'below','above')}),
    plots:-textplot([0, 0, sprintf("t = 1.00",a)],
                    align={piecewise(sin(1/(1-a))<0,'below','above'),
                           piecewise(sin(1/(1-a))<0,'left','right')}),
    plots:-pointplot([ff,[0,0]],color=blue,symbol=solidcircle,symbolsize=6), 
    plot([ee[], t=0 .. 99*a/100]),
    plot([ee[], t=a..1.0]),
    plot([ee[], t=99*a/100..a])
    ,scaling=unconstrained, axes=box
    , size=[600,500], gridlines
    , title=typeset([x,y]=ee,"\n\n t = ",0.0..1.00,"\n")
    ,labels=["",cat("",seq(" ",i=5-log[10](1/4*exp(1/(1-a)))..0,-1))]
    ,view=map(u->map(`*`,u,(4*exp(-1/(1-a)))),[-0.3..0.3,-0.3..0.3])
         ),
     parameters=[[a=0.0 .. 0.95, width=400, label=""]]):
```

If I'm lucky then that could be viewed (with a movable slider) as [spiral zoom](https://maple.cloud/app/5697745534320640/spiral+zoom?key=A4DAEAB62FB9489DA49DE4F4D8072FB3BD9DAC02418B4912982E5DEEF1B4EF13) on the Maple Cloud.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me in MATLAB R2016b, as far as I know it doesn't use anything version-specific.  I don't know Maple well enough to give a Maple version.

```
t = linspace(0,1,1000);
x = exp(-1./(1-t)).*cos(1./(1-t));
y = exp(-1./(1-t)).*sin(1./(1-t));
plot(x,y)
```

This gave me the following graph, which shows more of the spiral the more I zoom in.  The spiral shrinks so fast that you can't see more than about this much of it any any given zoom level.  For completeness sake, here is the link to the [Desmos demo](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/u7kvedu9n7) showing the same.

[image]